# Cómo pasar el valor de una caja de texto a otra página en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, formularios

El usuario debe ingresar un código en la caja "pin" y al seleccionar en los selectbox redirija a la página correspondiente dónde también hay una caja de texto pero esta caja deberá recibir lo que ingreso en formulario el usuario y aún no logro hacerlo. La redirección de las páginas ya funciona pero el envió hacia la caja de texto aún no.

Formulario:

```html
<form action="validar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <label>PIN Empresarial<span class='required'>*</span></label>
  <input type='text' form-control name='pin' id='pin' required="">

  <label>Te gusta la música?:</label>
  <select class='form-control' name='select1'>
    <option value='si' id="si1" name="si">SI</option>
    <option value='no' id="no0" name="no">NO</option>
  </select>

  <label>Te gusta leer?:</label>
  <select class='form-control' name='select2'>
    <option value='si' id="si11" name="si">SI</option>
    <option value='no' id="no00" name="no">NO</option>
  </select>
  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
```

Código Validar.php dónde se validan las selecciones y se envía a la página correspondiente que contendrá la caja de texto que recibirá lo escrito por el usuario en id='pin'.

```
<?php
$selectBox1 = $_POST["select1"]; 
$selectBox2 = $_POST["select2"];

if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: pagina1.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pagina2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pagina3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pagina4.php');
}
else {
header('Location: formulario.php');
} 
?>
```

Pagina 1,2,3,4 contendrán la caja de texto que recibirá de formulario, dependiendo de la selección selectbox del usuario.

Comment: ¿Lo siento pudieras editar y explicar mejor lo que deseas obtener?, pues no me es claro el resultado esperado

Comment: Listo @Aprendiz, lo siento por no haber sido tan claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript no sera tan práctico en este caso, la solución que te recomiendo es que lo pases haciendo un redireccionamiento con *header* pasando el parámetro pin en la url del `Location:` por `GET`, o que guardes la información en una variable `$_SESSION` y en las páginas pertinentes extraigas el valor de la variable que usaste.

Caso #1:

```
// archivo 'validar.php'
<?php 

$pin_obtenido = $_POST['pin'];

if(...) {
    header("Location: paginaX.php?var_pin=".($pin_obtenido));
}

 ?>

// archivo 'paginaX.php'
<?php 

$pin = $_GET['var_pin'];

 ?>
<!-- input en la paginaX -->
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $pin; ?>" \>
```

Caso #2:

```
// archivo 'validar.php'
<?php 
// inicializar el uso de variables de _SESSION
session_start();

$_SESSION['pin_guardado'] = $_POST['pin']; 

if(...) {
    header('Location: paginaX.php');
}

 ?>

 // archivo 'paginaX.php'
<?php 
// inicializar el uso de variables de _SESSION
session_start();

$pin = $_SESSION['pin_guardado'];

 ?>
<!-- input en la paginaX -->
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $pin; ?>" \>
```

Comment: GRACIAS me ha servido a la perfección¡

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con variables de session, en tu página principal quedaría así:

```
<?php
session_start();
$selectBox1 = $_POST["select1"]; 
$selectBox2 = $_POST["select2"];
$datos = $_POST['pin'];
$_SESSION['nombre_de_variable_'] = $datos; //Se puede pasar directamente, pero me gusta primero pasar a variable del $_POST.

if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: pagina1.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pagina2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pagina3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pagina4.php');
}
else {
header('Location: formulario.php');
} 
?>
```

Y al iniciar tus páginas obtienes de la variable de sesión a una local, de este modo.

```
session_start(); //recuerda siempre iniciar la sesión
$datosPin = $_SESSION['nombre_de_variable'];
```